# JSON passed from Javascript to C#

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to convert the the *regular* string literal below to valid JSON in C#

```
 "{\n\"connectionId\":\"mySQL1\",\n\"storedproc\":
 \"contactInsert\"\n\"params\":\n[\n{\"param\": \"@p_title\",
 \"val\":\"Mr\", \"dir\", \"in\"},\n{\"param\": \"@p_forename\",
 \"val\":\"Ronald\", \"dir\", \"in\"},\n{\"param\": \"@p_surname\",
 \"val\":\"Dobson\", \"dir\", \"in\"},\n{\"param\": \"@p_email\",
 \"val\":\"ron@hotmail.com\", \"dir\", \"in\"},\n{\"param\":
 \"@p_pwd\", \"val\":\"ron1227718\", \"dir\", \"in\"},\n{\"param\":
 \"@p_dateEntered\", \"val\":\"1955-11-25\", \"dir\",
 \"in\"},\n{\"param\": \"@p_partnerId\", \"val\":\"22\", \"dir\",
 \"in\"},\n{\"param\": \"@p_rowId\", \"val\":\"1955-11-25\", \"dir\",
 \"out\"}\n]\n}"
```

Things like this just don't seem to work:

```
JSONString = JSONString.Replace("\"",""").Replace("\n", "");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out [json2csharp](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: Most definitely use a JSON library for this kind of thing. After dealing with someone using a StringBuilder to create and serve XML to me, I can only hope you'll take the advice :)

Comment: I am using JSON.NET, but it offers no solution to the above.  My problem is the above contains characters that mean it is no longer valid JSON.  I just need to remove those characters which seem simple, but it isn't proving to be.

Comment: Inshort I need to replace \" with "  that is my main problem.

Comment: Seems like a problem better fixed on the sending side if possible. If the sender is claiming to be sending JSON, they should be sending JSON.

Comment: I agree with @itsme86. But if you really want to do this, you should `.Replace("\\\"","\"")`. Both back slash and the quotation mark must be escaped.

Comment: You have a reasonable point itsme86.  However before I go down that route I was just hoping that it would be possible to do a simple string replace in c#.  Not all that easy.

Comment: .Replace("\\\"","\"") does not work.  Tried and failed earlier.  How can this be so difficult?

Comment: Then you should at least report the errors. Are you sure that the string contains the back slashes? The Visual Studio debug view shows strings escaped. In this case, the back slashes would not actually be there.

Comment: Nico you solved my problem. Thank you.  I didn't realise that the back slashes were being cleared but still apparent in VS debug.  Thanks again I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a string representation of a JSON object. This is called the **serialized** object representation. You need to **deserialize** the string back into an actual JSON object. For that, use a JSON serializer such as JSON.NET

Answer (score 0):

Prob solved:

The Visual Studio debug view shows strings escaped. In this case, the back slashes would not actually be there. – Nico Schertler 12 mins ago

Nico you solved my problem. Thank you. I didn't realise that the back slashes were being cleared but still apparent in VS debug. Thanks again I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
JSONString = JSONString.Replace("\\\"", "\"");

JSONString= Line.Replace("\r\n", "\"").Replace("\n", "\"").Replace("\r", "\"");
```

However, I think the format should be handled on server/sender's side.